# Ubermenu mobile resolution

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I am using ubermenu and my menu items are images .
My problems is when I use mobile resolution to access the website, my menu items stay the same size which is really big .
I don't want to use a responsive menu , how I can make my menu to stretch when I use different resolutions?

Comment: without some example (at least a minimal setup on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ) it will be difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that you 'don't want to use a responsive menu', I see no other way (besides shrinking the images "manually" with fixed width values via css).

So for the responsive solution: By using following code

```
.theimagesclass {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

(got it from Bootstrap), you can make those images responsive and thus make them smaller on smaller devices.

If the images will behave strangely on bigger devices you can add a media query for the lower resolutions, for example:

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
    .navclass img {
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

This is just targeting the images inside the .navclass element, if the screen resolution is lower than 768px.